# Select Point by raster using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, point, select

I have some rasters with different morphological features each (slope, exposure etc), There is a way to select points (from a POINT shapefile) by a raster characteristics? (i.e. points in area with slope >25%).

There is, moreover, the possibility to select points combining 2 or more geomorphological feature (i.e. Point in area with slope >25 & Exposure from 45° to 90°)

I am using QGIS v2.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this directly if your data was in a PostGIS database.

But in QGIS you can also do this with point sampling, which will tag the raster values onto the point shapefile.

You have to install the "Point sampling tool" plugin. Which will appear in Plugins>Analyses>Point Sampling Tool.

This will create a new point shapefile with the raster values from the selected layers. Then you can do a select by attribute for the correct raster values.